# Read .csv that contains commas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file that contains multiple columns with texts in it. These texts contain commas, which makes things messy when I try to read the file into Python.

When I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
directory = 'some directory'

dataset = pd.read_csv(directory)
```

I got the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 42, saw 5
```

After doing some research, I found the `clevercsv` package.

So, I ran:

```
import clevercsv as csv

dataset = csv.read_csv(directory)
```

Running this, I got the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 4359705: character maps to <undefined>
```

To overcome this, I tried:

```
dataset = csv.read_csv(directory, encoding="utf8")
```

However, 10 hours later my computer was still working on reading it. So I expect that something went wrong there.

Furthermore, when I open the file in Excel, it does split cells well. Therefore, What I tried was to save the .csv file as a .xlsx and then save it as .csv in Python with an uncommon delimiter ('~'). However, when I save my .csv file as a .xlsx file, the size of the file gets smaller, which indicates that only a part of the file is saved and that is not what I want.

Lastly, I have tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750255/how-to-read-single-values-that-contains-commas-in-csv-file-using-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586748/parse-comma-separated-csv-file-with-quotes-in-python). But neither seem to work for my problem.

Given that Excel reads in the file without problems, I do expect that it should be possible to read it into Python as well. Who can help me with this?

UPDATE:

When using `dataset = pd.read_csv(directory, sep = ',', error_bad_lines=False)`I manage to read in the .csv. But many lines are skipped. Is there a better way for this?

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.read_csv('comma.csv', quotechar="'")`

Comment: That resulted in: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 42, saw 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panda should be work https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Dou you tried somthing like `dataset = pd.read_csv(directory, sep = ',', header = None)`

Regards

Comment: Yes, that gives me the error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 3